# Why do we prefer to use self.method() instead of Class.method(self)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

For example, for some class:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def something(self):    # yes I know this could be static
        print("something")
```

and instance

```
instance = Class()
```

the following are both technically valid:

```
instance.something()       # normal
Class.something(instance)  # but also technically valid
```

Is there some explicit reasoning why the first use case is preferred? I can think of examples like iterating over instances and calling methods, but I can also think of some cases where it may be easier to interpret my code when explicit reference to the Class I am using is visible.

> Apologies if this has been answered before. I could not find it, which may be due to my difficulty in phrasing the question.

Comment: Because `Class.method()` ties you to that class and you can't override the method anymore.

Comment: Your title and your question body differ rather a lot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes exactly, you may want to edit the title

Comment: I'm curious to see an example of where using `Class.method(self)` would make the code easier to understand.

Comment: @Blurp If you were reducing an iterable of objects to a single instance of that object by repeatedly calling a method between them, it could be reasonable. It would allow `reduce(MyClass.some_method, some_iterable)`.

Comment: @miradulo That's an interesting example, thanks. I think I might prefer a class method like `MyClass.reduce(instances)` though (if the point is to encapsulate some class-specific reduction logic).

Comment: @Blurp Oh for sure, I was just spitballing :)

Answer (score 7):

`Class.something(instance)` grabs the method from a *specific class*. `self.something()` uses the class for that instance, and that is *not necessarily the same class*.

You also repeat yourself a lot if you have to keep using the class name.

Your title uses `self`, which indicates code inside a method. Compare the output of the following examples:

```
class Animal:
    def make_sound(self):
        print('General nature sounds')

    def startle(self):
        self.make_sound()

    def pet(self):
        Animal.make_sound(self)

class Dog(Animal):
    def make_sound(self):
        # overrides Animal.make_sound()
        print('Bark!')

dog = Dog()
dog.startle()  # prints "Bark!"
dog.pet()      # prints "General nature sounds"
```

`Animal.make_sound(self)` works, but will use the original method, ignoring the new implementation for `Dog.make_sound()`.

For the case where you have a reference to an instance somewhere else, consider the case where you accept a class *or a subclass*:

```
class Cat(Animal):
    def make_sound(self):
        print('Meouw!')

def groom_pet(pet):
    pet.startle()
    Animal.make_sound(pet)

groom_pet(Cat())  # prints "Meouw", then "General nature sounds"
```

So we have a new subclass of `Animal`, and `groom_pet()` can accept any `Animal` instance, because subclasses will also have the same methods. But `pet.startle()` will end up calling the right `make_sound()` implementation, while `Animal.make_sound()` will again bypass the correct implementation.

Very rarely should you use the unbound class method over the bound method on an instance. There are reasons to use this *sometimes*; specifically if you want to bypass a parent class method (so not using `super().method()`), or if you want to improve performance and avoid looking up an attribute and binding the method in a tight loop.

Because such cases are rare and special, you want to stick to the *normal idiom*, because that aids understanding of your code for both yourself and other readers. Don't surprise those readers.